# Как вставить JS-скрипт в React класс?

Tags: reactjs

Мне нужно вставить js-скрипт в классовый компонент Реакта и сделать так, чтобы скрипт запускался только в тот момент, когда этот компонент уже смонтирован и физически есть в ДОМе. Как мне это сделать?
Благодарю за внимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй [`componentDidMount`](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)...

Comment: А в нём что написать?